# apc.filters on Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, alternative-php-cache

I set up OwnCloud on my Windows Server 2008 box. I run my blog on the machine as well and I wanted to set up APC. My blog runs fine with APC running, but for some reason it causes a bunch of javascript errors with OwnCloud. I tried to set up apc.filters to exclude OwnCloud but no matter what I try it doesn't seem to make a difference. Anyone know the proper syntax with Windows directory paths?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a line from my WampDeveloper server (Apache and PHP on Windows) for APC filters to exclude a couple of things. You should be able to infer the syntax.

`apc.filters="apc\.php$,phpinfo\.php$,.*phpMyAdmin.*"`

apc.filters - http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters

> A comma-separated list of POSIX extended regular expressions. If any
>   pattern matches the source filename, the file will not be cached. Note
>   that the filename used for matching is the one passed to
>   include/require, not the absolute path. If the first character of the
>   expression is a + then the expression will be additive in the sense
>   that any files matched by the expression will be cached, and if the
>   first character is a - then anything matched will not be cached. The -
>   case is the default, so it can be left off.

So don't use full paths. Just file names. And from testing before, don't even try to use folders (no folders anywhere in the string)... I could never get that to work.